# What API level for GCM without Google account?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

What API Level should I target for a GCM application in order for a Google account not being required? Is a Google account required for GCM on a low API level device even if I am using the Play Services implementation of GCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one hand, the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) say :

> it uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android **4.0.4** or higher.

On the other hand, [this post from the android-gcm group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-gcm/keneth/android-gcm/ecG-RfH-Aso/9-s5pFkumzIJ) (made by Costin Manolache), implies that the new Google Play Services library makes the Google Account unnecessary for older versions too :

> Some background: 
>   **Froyo and Gingerbread registration is implemented in GoogleServicesFramework, using the Google account for registration**. This has resulted in a lot of auth errors for people where the account was not in a good state.
>
> **Starting with ICS, GCM doesn't depend or uses the Google account** - you can use it before you add an account or without any accounts.
>
> **The "Play Services" update is implementing the new scheme on all devices** - but it seems a small number of devices have problems with this, we're investigating - but the numbers are far lower than those with the old scheme.

Comment: Does API level 15 include 4.0.3?

Comment: @user3935018 Yes, according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html), which makes you wonder why the GCM docs mention version 4.0.4 or higher and not 4.0.3.

Comment: So do I need to worry about missing account errors if I set the min sdk value at 15 and am using the play services library?